# FFMpeg kmsgrab record pixels wrong

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-capture

ffmpeg -f kmsgrab -i - -framerate 60 -vf 'hwdownload,format=bgr0' -preset ultrafast out.mkv

This is how a video frame should look like
[image: kitty terminal emulator in the wayland]
This is how it is recorded by ffmpeg[image: kitty terminal emulator in the wayland][image: weston-simple-egl]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jOUTk3ZxOfwnfd7zS4d4qBLApTS3Vmx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Add the filter hwmap before the hwdownload.
It should look something like this
`-vf 'hwmap=derive_device=vaapi,hwdownload,format=bgr0'`.